# how can i stop scrolling when in the process of a swipe using hammer js?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using hammerjs to allow horizontal swiping through images in a gallery , is there a way for me to stop vertical scrolling while the user is swiping horizontally?

Comment: Is the element in a modal or built into the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a drag handler with the drag_lock_to_axis option set to true - see the inline documention in the [Hammer.js drag source code](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/blob/master/src/gestures/drag.js#L31).

This should keep the drag gesture from causing vertical scrolling in the swipe area.  Note that this option will cause a slight lag in vertical scrolling as it tries to determine the direction of drag.  You can also use drag_block_vertical to just prevent vertical scrolling in that area all together though this is generally not desirable.